# Is there an issue with conflicting class names using boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I am implementing a solver for the max closure of a graph using the push relabel max flow algorithm from the boost library.

I have a custom class called Graph, which holds all of the problem information; however, I was looking at the implementation of the push relabel algorithm in the boost library, and it also defines a custom class called Graph. Will these conflicting class names cause an issue?

My solver is a small part of a larger project, so I don't have any control over class names unfortunately.

Comment: Please read up on namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem if the names are in different namespaces and you don't do something silly like `using namespace whatever`.

Comment: So if it has `typedef <some type definition> Graph;` and i have a class defined called Graph; then there will be no problem defining, say `std::vector<Graph>` so long as I dont say "using namespace boost"?

Comment: If there's a class named `boost::Graph` and you write a class named `my_wonderful_stuff::Graph` (or even `Graph`, in the global namespace) the two names are different. You can create conflicts with various forms of `using`, so don't do that without thinking it through.